# Matrix(row, col) = value

Tags: c++, matrix

```
double Matrix::operator()(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return m[a*rows+b];
}
```

I have the above currently for accessing the value stored in the matrix, however I'd like to be able to set the value at that position. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about returning a reference:

```
double& Matrix::operator()(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return m[a*rows+b];
}
```

Then you can set the value of the corresponding element.

Comment: You should also have a `const` overload (returning either a value or `const` reference), in order to access the elements of a `const` matrix.

Comment: Totally true, you should add a const version. I would also propose to use the operator[] instread of operator().  
Since () is usually used for function calls and [] for accessing elements. But this depends on your taste.

Comment: @tgmath - There is a problem with operator[] only taking one parameter. You would have to add some sort of proxy class with another operator[] to get matrix[i][j].

Comment: @Bo Persson: In this case, the "proxy class" is just a double* - `return m + a * rows;` (Yes, I know this prevents boundary checks etc, but the OP doesn't do those anyways)

Comment: @Steven: "Works like a charm, thanks" is best expressed as a [green tick to the left of the answer that helped you most](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).